# PHP: Variable into string query

Tags: php, postgresql, variables

I'm trying to do a query based into a value obtained in a previous query. Something like that:

```
$variableid = 100;

$query_prev = "SELECT query FROM queries_table WHERE id = 1";
$result_prev = pg_query($pg,$query_prev);
$row_prev = pg_fetch_array($result_prev);


$final_query = $row_prev['query']; 

$row_prev['query'] value would be "SELECT * FROM other_table WHERE id = $variableid";

$final_query value at this point is: "SELECT * FROM other_table WHERE id = $variableid"

/* but that I want is this value: */ "SELECT * FROM other_table WHERE id = 100"
```

Comment: You're storing SQL in the database? **WHY**?

Comment: My best advice is DO NOT DO THIS, IT IS A TERRIBLE IDEA. Whatever you are trying to actually achieve (unclear from your question), trust me there's a better way.

Comment: Is it important Marc b?

Comment: @user3438090 It could be important to understand what you are trying to achieve, because there may be a better solution to the original problem, which completely avoids the complexities you are finding with your current approach. This is known as [the X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If you find the answer to your own question, you should post it as an Answer below, and accept it, rather than editing the question. This makes it clearer that the question has been answered, and keeps the site easier to read for later visitors. Although $deity help any visitor who sees this and thinks evaluating a string from the DB as both PHP code *and* SQL is anything other than an incredibly bad idea.

Comment: @IMSoP Not allowed to do that after 8 hours. I'm noob here and I haven't enough points xD

Answer (score 0):

Use if statement before you do the next select so:

```
<?php if ($row_prev['query']= 100){

    SELECT .......... etc.
    }else
    SELECT from other

    ?>
```

/Hope that's what you wanted

Comment: Thanks a lot Ria but not, eval is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
$variableid = 100;

$query_prev = "SELECT query FROM queries_table WHERE id = 1";
$result_prev = pg_query($pg,$query_prev);
$row_prev = pg_fetch_array($result_prev);
$query = $row_prev['query']; 

eval("\$final_query = \"$query\";");
```